# Определить цикличность в связанном списке

Tags: java, linked-list

Добрый день. Задан связанный список.

```
class Node<T> {
   T value;
   Node<T> next;
}

Node first = new Node(1);
Node two = new Node(2);
Node third = new Node(3);
Node four = new Node(4);

first.next = two;
two.next = third;
third.next = four;
four.next = first;
```

Написать алгоритм определяющий, что список содержит замыкания.

```
boolean hasCycle(Node first);
```

Обратите внимание, что список может быть замкнут и в середине. К примеру, 3-й узел будет ссылаться на 2-й узел. Определение зацикленности необходимо реализовать путем прохода по узлам, без использования коллекций.

Как реализовать проверку? В интернете нашел решение, но что если цикл будет зациклен в середине. Каким образом можно это реализовать?

Comment: Тот, кто дал вам это задание, хочет проверить не вашу способность искать решения в интернете или задавать вопросы на SO, а ваше логическое мышление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Алгоритм «черепахи и зайца» Флойда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0#%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%86)

```
public static boolean hasCycle(Node first) {
    Node turtle = first;
    Node hare = first;

    while (hare != null && hare.next != null) {
        tortoise = tortoise.next;
        hare = hare.next.next;
        if (tortoise == hare) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю буду разбираться .